# SSRS - Calculating percentage based on calculated field

Tags: reporting-services, service, reporting

When I tried this

```
=Count(Fields!Refcode.Value) / Sum(count(Fields!Refcode.Value), "Branch")*100
```

This was the response I got

> The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox130’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Comment: It's complaining about the `Branch`. Without more information and detail it's hard to help. At what level do you have this expression? Detail? Subtotal? Grand Total?

Comment: I  tried  =Count(Fields!RefNo.Value)/Count(Fields!ExternalWorkPlacementActualHours.Value, "GP01a") But the calculated percentage was wrong at the subtotal level

Comment: What is the "Branch" scope, is it a dataset name or row group name etc? Make sure the scope is spelled exactly the same as the scope object, it is case sensitive.

Comment: I suggest you add a screenshot of your tablix so that we can see what this refers to, and information on the groupings.